# How to auto populate users information from Sharepoint into infopath

Tags: infopath

I am trying to create a user form in InfoPath 2010 from SharePoint 2010 for certification. Please help, I'm new to InfoPath. thanks

Comment: can you elaborate your question a little bit more?

Comment: You're going to have to give us a lot more detail. What is the form supposed to do? Will it be in a form library, or is this a new/edit form? What do you mean by certification?

Comment: I want to display the list items in InfoPath itself, if I select emp id, should display automatically all the info related that employee in InfoPath itself. This form will be use to recertify all users on our SharePoint site. User will have to fill out this form quarterly to keep access active. Hopefully this explain it better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent article explaining how to use SharePoint SOAP service (`userprofileservice.asmx`) to fetch user information and populate fields on the form using that information.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thank you Harry, let me try this site and I will let you know the outcome.